# Title of Office.context.ui.disaplogAsync

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel, excel-web-addins

I want to change the title of dialog box of office. I am not able to change the name of title.

[image: 1]

It display the whole url. How to add the title instead of URL.

Answer (score 2):

The title of the dialog cannot be changed - this is by design. This is to prevent spoofing as the title displays the URL of the page that is loaded. See [How to change the Dialog title? #2373](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2373) for more information.

There is no property or element in the manifest to specify the caption for dialogs. `OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: can we hide this title?

Comment: The name of your add-in will be used for the title when it is published/deployed.